# Pandas: How to correctly parse a dashed text flat file into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have one ugly text file that looks like this:

```
2020-06-13
----------------------------------------
|Order    |Warehouse|Stock|Price|Vendor| 
|--------------------------------------|
|31434    |WA12     |200  |160  |AS12  |
|31435    |WA11     |26   |12   |AS11  |
|31436    |WA13     |202  |161  |AS16  |
----------------------------------------
2020-06-14
----------------------------------------
|Order    |Warehouse|Stock|Price|Vendor| 
|--------------------------------------|
|31437    |WA12     |200  |160  |AS12  |
|31438    |WA11     |26   |12   |AS11  |
|31439    |WA13     |202  |161  |AS16  |
----------------------------------------
```

I try to parse it using the read_csv function like so:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='|', error_bad_lines=False)
```

But my dataframe comes out with a lot of notable  problems:

First problem, the first dashed lines (before the headers) and I also assume the last dashed lines (the footer) get inserted into the *Material* column and every other field in that row (Warehouse, Stock, Price, Vendor) is set to NaN

- Is there a way to skip these dashed lines: `----------------------------------------` ?
- Second problem, is the separator | which shows up before and after the headers. Before *Order* and after *Vendor*

  |*Order*    |Warehouse|Stock|Price|*Vendor*|

  This make pandas return two NaN headers with empty values inside of them
- Third problem is how to ignore this line |--------------------------------------| as well?

Sorry if this question sounds confusing. I'm confused as well if this is the proper way to do it by changing the parameters the read_csv function takes or do I need to normalize/sanitize/clean the file before sending it to the read_csv function by doing some pure python?

Thank you

Comment: Use a text editor with good regex support (Sublime, Notepad++, VSCode, etc.) to remove and/or alter the problematic lines.

Comment: Hello Hohnny! Your data requires dates to be one column? e.g. Dates,Order, Warehouse,Stock,Price,Vendor

Comment: Hi. The only way I see is to iterate over the "blocks" using regex and store the line contents into a list. Then you would use this to init the dataframe. I would use 3 regex: one for the blocks (to iterate), one for the date (because it's one date for many lines) and other for the lines itself. If there is no neeed of the dates, then use only the first and last regex.

Comment: @JoãoVictor When you say to store the lien contents you mean the values right?

Comment: @LucasCorbanez Yes date is important I forgot to mention

Comment: @MattDMo Problem is I'd like to automatize it and I have a whole lot of the same type of file but for different dates

Comment: @Johnnyboy, I have placed an answer based on the data you have which gives me the desired Datarame, hope that will help.

Comment: @Johnnyboy, if  if helps you also have liberty to up vote as well :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This data is really tricky as you said, So, we have to pay logic another way around:

### raw_data as provided:

```
$ cat weired_data
----------------------------------------
|Order    |Warehouse|Stock|Price|Vendor|
|--------------------------------------|
|31434    |WA12     |200  |160  |AS12  |
|31435    |WA11     |26   |12   |AS11  |
|31436    |WA13     |202  |161  |AS16  |
----------------------------------------
2020-06-14
----------------------------------------
|Order    |Warehouse|Stock|Price|Vendor|
|--------------------------------------|
|31437    |WA12     |200  |160  |AS12  |
|31438    |WA11     |26   |12   |AS11  |
|31439    |WA13     |202  |161  |AS16  |
----------------------------------------
```

### Cleaning data to form DataFrame:

This is how you can parse your data to create a desired DataFrame:

```
#!/home/nxf59093/Karn_python3/bin/python
import pandas as pd
##### Python pandas, widen output display to see more columns. ####
#pd.set_option('display.height', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.width', None)
pd.set_option('expand_frame_repr', True)
##################################################################
# read the with `read_csv`
df = pd.read_csv("weired_data")
# replace all hyphens and pipes using `str.replace`
df['2020-06-13'] = df['2020-06-13'].str.replace('|', '')
df['2020-06-13'] = df['2020-06-13'].str.replace('-', '')
# as every row contains `31` and that's the way to pick the lines  
df = df[df['2020-06-13'].str.contains('31')]
# as default it has `2020-06-13` column name hence we'll Limit 
# number of splits in output by using `n=5` as we need 5 columns which 
# will return ` 0     1    2    3     4` columns names
df = df['2020-06-13'].str.split(n=5, expand=True)
# as we have got column names which we can rename as we want them to be
df = df.rename(columns={0: 'Order', 1: 'Warehouse', 2: 'Stock',  3: 'Price', 4: 'Vendor'})
print(df)
```

### Desired Parsed DataFrame:

```
 $ ./test_data.py
    Order Warehouse Stock Price Vendor
3   31434      WA12   200   160   AS12
4   31435      WA11    26    12   AS11
5   31436      WA13   202   161   AS16
11  31437      WA12   200   160   AS12
12  31438      WA11    26    12   AS11
13  31439      WA13   202   161   AS16
```

**Another Method with less slicing:**

```
df = pd.read_csv("weired_data", sep="|", skiprows=2, index_col=0)
df = df.dropna(axis=0,how='all')
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '')
df = df[df['Order'].str.contains('31')]
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.dropna(axis=1,how='all')
print(df)
```

**Result:**

```
   Order      Warehouse  Stock  Price  Vendor
0  31434      WA12       200    160    AS12
1  31435      WA11       26     12     AS11
2  31436      WA13       202    161    AS16
3  31437      WA12       200    160    AS12
4  31438      WA11       26     12     AS11
5  31439      WA13       202    161    AS16
```

In case you want your data to be looked like as sql tables then you need to use tabulate and print that .

```
from tabulate import tabulate
print(tabulate(df,  headers='keys', tablefmt='psql', showindex=False))


+-----------+-------------+---------+---------+----------+
|     Order | Warehouse   |   Stock |   Price | Vendor   |
|-----------+-------------+---------+---------+----------|
| 31434     | WA12        |   200   |   160   | AS12     |
| 31435     | WA11        |   26    |   12    | AS11     |
| 31436     | WA13        |   202   |   161   | AS16     |
| 31437     | WA12        |   200   |   160   | AS12     |
| 31438     | WA11        |   26    |   12    | AS11     |
| 31439     | WA13        |   202   |   161   | AS16     |
+-----------+-------------+---------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: the way you slice the wired_data is way better. But as Johnnyboy said, those dates are an important information for the parsed DataFrame.

Comment: @LucasCorbanez, Yeah, i have given Just a way around, however i have placed another way around., may be that may help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

file = open('weird_data.txt', 'r').read()

###Removing strange characters###
to_replace = ['\n', '--------------------------------------', ' ']
for char in to_replace:
    file = file.replace(char, '')
    
file = file.replace('--', '')

###Removing column names. I will only work with the pattern###    
column_names = ['Order','Warehouse','Stock','Price','Vendor']
for name in column_names:
    file = file.replace(name, '')
    
file = file.replace('|||||||||', '|')

###Here we get all the possible dates###
dates = re.findall('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', file)

###Here we split out string between every possible date###
undated_rows = re.split('\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}', file)[1::]

print('Date|Order|Warehouse|Stock|Price|Vendor', file = open('regular_data.txt', 'w')) ###This is the first line of our csv with the column names###


rows = []
for t in zip(dates, undated_rows): ###This zip every line with it's respective date
    row = list(t[1])
    row[0] = t[0]
    row.insert(1, '|')
    row = ''.join(row)
    row = row.replace('||', '\n'+t[0]+'|')
    if row[-1] == '|':
        row = row[0:-1]
    print(row, file = open('regular_data.txt', 'a'))

df = pd.read_csv('regular_data.txt', sep = '|')
```

I believe this a very manual solution, but it works.